# optimize a function in presence of NAs values in R

Tags: r, missing-data, extreme-value

I would like to maximize the `funcToOpt` in the code.

Description of the data:

1. `wb` and `X1` are T x N matrix, and `Nt` a vector of length N
2. the sum of each row of `wb` is 1
3. `X1` is cross-sectionally standardized (mean=1 sd=0)

The standardization implies that the cross-sectional average of `theta*X1` is zero, which means that `rowSums(wb + (theta1*X1) / Nt)` is always 1. 
**This happens to me just when i work with a X1 matrix without NAs values, is there someone that know how i can have row sum of `wi` equal to 1 when using a matrix with NAs as well??**

CODE OF THE MAXIMIZATION:

```
X1 <- t(scale(t((X1))))    # X1 STANDARDIZATION
N <- dim(X1)[2]
T <- dim(X1)[1]

M <- wb + r + X1                  # Nt, counting the NAs values
Nt <- rowSums(!is.na(M)) 

funcToOpt <- function (theta1)
{
  inner <- rowSums((wb + (theta1*X1) / Nt) * r,na.rm = TRUE)  

  return (sum(inner, na.rm=TRUE) / T)
}

max<-optimize(funcToOpt, c(-50, 50), maximum = TRUE)

theta1=max[[1]]                                 

wi=wb+(theta1*X1) / Nt     
rowSums(wi,na.rm=T)
```

MATRIX 5X5 WITHOUT NA

```
r=matrix(c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.1),ncol = 5)
wb=matrix(c(0.3,0.3,-0.4,-0.3,0.4,-0.5,-0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.1),ncol = 5)
X1=matrix(c(1:20,0,4,5,0,3),ncol = 5)
```

MATRIX 5x5 with NA

```
r=matrix(c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.1),ncol = 5)
wb=matrix(c(0.3,0.3,-0.4,-0.3,0.4,-0.5,-0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.1),ncol = 5)
X1=matrix(c(1:20,NA,4,5,NA,3),ncol = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First this questions should be on stackoverflow.

Regarding the NA's the problem:

```
inner <- rowSums((wb + (theta1*X1) / Nt) * r,na.rm = TRUE)
```

The value of `theta*X1` here is not same for `X1` with & without NA's as you are only taking into account NA's for `rowSum` of `wb + (theta1*X1) / Nt) * r` this complete term.

Fix this & it will be correct.

Comment: Could you be more cleare please? Your words could be very helpfull

Comment: In the line I have pointed out check the output of the term "Theta1*X1" for both the values of X1. You will notice that the NAs are not taken care of in this multiplication (because na.rm is not applicable here). This is resulting in the different value of the of inner in both cases & thus different "wi" a the end.

Comment: Also refer to this question, this is how your NA's are getting carried forward & not removed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535084/matrix-multiplication-with-scattered-na-values

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, i have checked Theta1*X1 output for both case. So i found the "problem",but still not a solution for have always "rowSums(wi)" equal to 1. Do you know something or someone who can help me? Thanks

Comment: For my case I can't change NA with 0

Comment: then your code is correct. Output with NAs will not be same as output with zero.